# Making Apps using flutter

Tags: flutter, app-store

Is it possible to build a fully functioning application for iOS and Android using AndroidStudio + Flutter and FireBase alone? This is my first time trying to make a fully functioning mobile application which I want to use as I am constrained with my finances at the moment. I would appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Hi, @Aurrora if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: The answer to your question can be found on several articles on the web if you search for it. If you get stuck somewhere while building your app, now it's time ask it here.

Comment: I have to add that if you want to do something very platform-specific (which is mostly rare ) you might want to do native. I would advise you to check that all the features that you want in your app can be done using flutter, before starting development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Flutter can produce a fully functioning application for both iOS and Android platforms.

there are some apps built with Flutter. check them [here](https://flutter.dev/showcase)

I am a native Android developer and I did some iOS as well. I started learning Flutter a couple of days ago and it seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to make both Android and IOS app using flutter and dart.

Flutter has many benefits. here some example :

1. Flutter hot reload helps you to build your app very fast.
2. User fluent. Can use app with excellent  user interface design.
3. It's easy to use function like other OOP languages.
4. Update everyday with new features.
5. Flutter user community is increasing day by day .

[Check the flutter docs for more info](https://flutter.dev/docs)